# ¿Cómo restar 15 minutos a una marca de tiempo de pandas que tiene unidades 'ms' en Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, date, timestamp

Suponga que usted tiene la siguiente `df`:

```
          End Date         Close Price

2022-05-12 09:59:59.999000     0.00711
2022-05-12 10:14:59.999000     0.00704
2022-05-12 10:29:59.999000     0.00712
```

La columna `['End Date']` fue establecida como la columna index de la `df`

Al ejecutar:

> `In [1]: df.index[0]`

Usted obtiene:

> `Out[1]: Timestamp('2022-05-12 09:59:59.999000')`

¿Cómo podría usted sustraer 15 minutos del valor `df.index[0]` con el fin de obtener la siguiente salida?

> `Out[2]: Timestamp('2022-05-12 09:44:59.999000')`

Comment: Buen día, recuerda siempre agregar a tus preguntas lo que has intentado, parte importante de la cultura del sitio es mostrar un esfuerzo por resolver tus propias dudas. (Tuve que ocultar mi respuesta momentáneamente hasta que agregues lo que has intentado). Haz hecho buenas preguntas anteriormente, no pierdas la costumbre de hacerlas de la misma forma. Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucionado, era muy sencillo en realidad:

> `In [1]: df.index[0] - pd.DateOffset(minutes=15)`

> `Out [1]: Timestamp('2022-05-12 09:44:59.999000')`

Fuente: https://thispointer.com/how-to-add-minutes-to-datetime-in-python/

Comment: Buen día, es correcto, muy bien! Encontraste la respuesta a tu propia pregunta! Voy a mostrar nuevamente la respuesta que había ocultado que utiliza el mismo método que la tuya. Por favor acepta tu propia respuesta como correcta, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la respuesta a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

La forma más fácil de hacerlo es utilizando [`pandas.Timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html).

Cree un `dataframe` de prueba en el archivo "sample2.csv" utilizando los datos de tu pregunta y configuré la columna "End Date" como índice y es de tipo `datetime`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample2.csv', index_col='End Date')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.to_markdown()
```

Esto devuelve:

| End Date | Close Price |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-05-12 09:59:59.999000 | 0.00711 |
| 2022-05-12 10:14:59.999000 | 0.00704 |
| 2022-05-12 10:29:59.999000 | 0.00712 |

Lo único que hay que hacer es

```
df.index = df.index - pd.Timedelta(minutes=15)
```

Al imprimir nuevamente el `dataframe` obtenemos:

| End Date | Close Price |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-05-12 09:44:59.999000 | 0.00711 |
| 2022-05-12 09:59:59.999000 | 0.00704 |
| 2022-05-12 10:14:59.999000 | 0.00712 |